# How do I add line breaks to my array output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var d0 = document.getElementById("d0").getElementsByTagName('h2');
var pp0 = document.getElementById("prepend0").getElementsByClassName('formDiv');
//alert(d0.length);
//alert(pp0.length);
var report ="";
for (var i = 0; i < d0.length; i++) {
    report += d0[i].textContent+"%0D%0A";//gets the date for day1
    for (var j = 0; j < pp0.length; j++) {
        report += pp0[j].textContent+"%0D%0A";//gets the d0 formDiv children. I want to out put this with line breaks
    }     
}
```

OutPut:

```
Sun Apr 19 2015 
Project OneEnter Description Here.Total Time: 00:00:00
```

What I want to do is:

```
Sun Apr 19 2015 
Project One
Enter Description Here.
Total Time: 00:00:00
```

Comment: the second comment should read "//gets the prepend0 formDiv children for day1"

Comment: If your output goes out as `HTML` then you should use `<br/>` instead of "%0D%0A".  The latter is treated as white space and does not cause a newline in a web page.

Comment: It is going out to Microsoft Outlook and html tags arent making it thru.

Comment: Have you tried '\n' ?

Comment: Why are you percent-escaping your line breaks? Shouldn't the part of you code that sends the `report` string elsewhere do this?

Answer (score 0):

`%0D%0A` are *url encoded* versions of line breaks, and as such you should be seeing the literal `%0D` and `%0A` characters instead of "nothing" that your example shows.

For plaintext views, such as in a text file, "View Source" in a browser, or within a `<pre>` tag, you'll want to use `\r\n` instead:

```
report += d0[i].textContent + "\r\n";
```

However, if you want the newlines to display in HTML (outside of the `<pre>` tag), you'll want to use `<br />`:

```
report += d0[i].textContent + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you gone to print to console:

```
console.log("1111\ncdcd")
```

and if its HTML:

```
$(element).text("AAAA <br/> BBBB <br/> CCCCC")
```